# Which PIE participle corresponds to PGmc past participle?

Tags: proto-indo-european

Which PIE participle (active/middle/passive voice) corresponds to PGmc past participle?

Answer (score 1):

The Proto-Germanic (and Latin, and others) past passive participles correspond with the Proto-Indo-European verbal adjectives:

From Beekes' 2011 p. 280:

> **18.9.2 The verbal adjective**
> This is an adjective that is not derived from a tense stem, as is the participle, but from
> a root. The most frequently found is the adjective in **-to-* the root has zero grade.
>  
>     Skt. **syūtá-*‚ ‘sewn’, OCS šitъ < **sjū-tъ*, Lith. *siṹ-tas*
>     Skt. **gatá-*, Gr. **batós*, Lat. *(in)-ventus* ‘arrived’ < **g<sup>w</sup>m-tó-*
>     Lat. *tentus* ‘stretched’ < **tn-to-*
>     Arm. *lu* ‘known’ < **ḱlu-tó-*
>     Goth. *nasiþs* ‘saved’ < **-tó-s*

> **Germanic uses this suffix to form the verbal adjective of weak verbs, as in E. *fill-ed.***  [Emphasis mine.]

> The same function as **-to-* was fulfilled by **-no-*:
>     Skt. *bhinná-* < **b<sup>h</sup>id-nó-* ‘split’
>     Skt. *pūrṇá-* ‘full, filled’, OCS *plъnъ*, Lith. *pìlnas*, OIr. *lán*, Goth. *fulls*, all from **plh<sub>1</sub>-no-*, Lat. *plēnus* (with full grade)

> The suffix form **-eno-* is found in OCS *vlьčenъ* ‘pulled’. In Germanic **-ono-* is used for the strong verbs: Goth. *bit-ans* < **-onos, E. *bitten* (sometimes **-ino-*: Runic *slaginaz*,
> OS *geslegen* ‘beaten’).

In PIE, these weren't participles proper, but verbal adjectives, even if many daughter languages they functioned like participles:

From [Luraghi, Inglese, and Kölligan 2021](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/flin-2021-2033/html?lang=en#j_flin-2021-2033_s_004_s_002):

> Ancient IE languages attest to nominal forms of the verb, participles and verbal adjectives that may have a passive orientation when based on transitive verbs, that is, they may profile the event encoded by the base verb from the perspective of the Patient or P-participant. Notably, though the details of the morphological shape and the semantics of these morphemes differ in the IE languages, most of these forms, e.g. *-nt- participles, **-to-*, **-no-*, and **-lo-* verbal adjectives, can be traced back to PIE (see Adrados et al. 2016: 369–375; Beekes 2011: 279–280; Fortson 2010: 108–109; Meier-Brügger 2010: 317–320, 421). **It must be stressed that in the system of the proto-language these were derivational deverbal morphemes, i.e. they were not obligatory and were not integrated in verbal inflectional paradigms, as is also shown by their partly idiosyncratic semantics. Accordingly, the *-nt- and the *-to- suffixes were used to derive verbal adjectives from verb bases and were originally indifferent to voice distinctions (Melchert 2017; Szemerényi 1996).**